# Cómo ingresar datos en un arreglo diferente a esta forma

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy haciendo una clase que necesita **consultar datos de este arreglo** para mostrar una imagen determinada.

Quién nos enseña, nos dio esta forma:

```
var imagenes=[];
imagenes["Cauchin"]="vaca.png";
imagenes["Pocacho"]="pollo.png";
imagenes["Tocinaurio"]="cerdo.png";
```

Pero **se ve bastante ineficiente** a mi parecer si en un futuro necesito tener cientos de datos.

descubrí la forma de hacerlo con la sintaxis de JSON, pero no es lo que busco, 
**¿Cómo es la sintaxis correcta para introducir los datos dentro de un arreglo si usar diferentes lineas de código**?

codigo completo:

```
var imagenes=[];
imagenes["Cauchin"]="vaca.png";
imagenes["Pocacho"]="pollo.png";
imagenes["Tocinaurio"]="cerdo.png";

class pakiman
{
    constructor(n,v,a)
    {
        this.imagen= new Image();
        this.nombre=n;
        this.vida=v;
        this.ataque=a;

        this.imagen.src=imagenes[this.nombre];
    }
    hablar()
    {
        document.writeln(this.nombre+" dice: "+this.nombre+"..."+this.nombre+"<br/>")
    }
    mostrar()
    {
        document.body.appendChild(this.imagen);
        document.writeln("<br/>"+"Nombre: "+this.nombre+"<br/>"+"Vida: "+this.vida+"<br/>"+"Ataque: "+this.ataque);
    }
}
var Pocacho = new pakiman("Pocacho",120,40);
var Tocinaurio = new pakiman("Tocinaurio",200,25)
var Cauchin = new pakiman("Cauchin",120,50)

console.log(Pocacho,Tocinaurio,Cauchin);
Pocacho.hablar();
Pocacho.mostrar();
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Yo uso la función [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push). Si tenes varias inserciones, las recorres con un for y vas insertando en cada iteración.

Comment: Este no es Javascript válido. A lo mejor tu profesor dijo `var imagenes={}; ` (o sea un objeto) en lugar de `var imagenes=[];` (array o arreglo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var datos = ["vaca.png","pollo.png","cerdo.png"]
var imagenes=[];
for (var i = datos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    imagenes.push(datos[i])
}
console.log(imagenes)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]